# ThinkPad T430s SSD freezing after started

Tags: windows-8, ssd, freeze

My ThinkPad T430s notebook with Windows 8 64 bit always freezes after start. It takes about 30s to 1 min until it freezes. If I disable the mini SSD(15G) in my notebook, it will work well. But every time I enable the SSD, the problem comes back. Does anyone have an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: run a diag tool and look if the SSD has SMART errors. The mini-SSD is used as Cache. Make sure you use the latest Intel drivers.

Comment: I have ran a test and it says the SSD don't support SMART, how to fix it?

Comment: which SSD do you use? Do you known this?

Comment: My SSD is SanDisk SSD U100 16GB

Comment: which tool have you used?

Comment: I am using lenovo solution center's hardware test function

Comment: check this: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/targeted-read-test-failed/td-p/936391 others also seam to have issues with the SSD. Contact their support, maybe your SSD is damaged.